# An error occurred {"type":"PLATFORM_ERROR", "payload":"0"}, while updating merchant information in google play

Tags: google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-services

I am trying to update Merchant Information in my Google play account. I have two queries on this,

1. Before I could do anything on this page, there is an error window as, 
    An error occurred {"type":"PLATFORM_ERROR", "payload":"0"}. 
   How to resolve this?
2. Google play requires business website under the 'Merchant Information' section. What should
   I put there?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with the help of Google play support team. Needed to clear the browser cache and cookies. Besides, keeping the system time consistent with the current time(which was wrong initially).